# How to connect php and composer image using docker-composer?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to connect php and composer image, so that I can run a laravel app inside docker.

Following is what I tried, is there something I doing wrong?

**step1. create a simple laravel app at localhost.**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel-app 5.6
```

**step2. create docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        image: php:7-fpm
        ports: 
          - "3021:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
    composer:
        image: composer:latest
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
        working_dir: /app
        command: ["install","php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0"]
        depends_on:
            - php
```

After that, I run **docker-compose up --force-recreate -d** and access **127.0.0.1:3021** at browser, but I get nothing.

Then I run docker-composer log, it shows me this error message:

```
Invalid argument php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0. Use "composer require php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0" instead to add packages to your composer.json.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Start of by seeing if your containers are actually running (`docker-compose ps`) and look if you can find any errors (`docker-compose logs`). This can literally be a 100 different things.

Comment: @Blizz Hello, thanks for telling me how to see the config of  docker-compose. It shows this message "Invalid argument php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0. Use "composer require php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0" instead to add packages to your composer.json."

Comment: Composer is php management, if you don't want to install it locally you can indeed use the docker container to run it once so you get the laravel project created. It should not be in your docker compose. The `artisan serve` is the laravel php command that sets up the dev-webserver and should be part of your php container. Don't want to be disrespectful but perhaps your trying to chew off too much at once?

Comment: @Blizz I'm probably doing something wrong, but if I run for example `docker run  --rm -it -volume $PWD:/app composer create-project laravel/laravel .` I can't see the Laravel app being installed. Probably haven't set correct the volumes to map with my app container?